# getting error on 6th line of the following code

Tags: c#

```
    private void pictureBox1_Paint_1(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Pen graphPen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);
        Point pt1D = new Point();
        Point pt2D = new Point();
        pt1D.X = textBox3.Text.ToString();
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(graphPen, pt1D, pt2D);

    }
```

I'm getting error on 6th line as: `cannot convert type string to int.`

Comment: Where is the question? Have you tried learning about [data types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173104(v=vs.80).aspx) and in particular [value types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch(v=vs.80).aspx)? Have you tried _anything_?

Comment: Vague title is unlikely to help future visitors with the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the string from your text box to an integer:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint_1(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Pen graphPen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);
    Point pt1D = new Point();
    Point pt2D = new Point();
    int xCoord = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
    pt1D.X = xCoord;
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(graphPen, pt1D, pt2D);

}
```

Comment: This _could_ work, some of the time.

Comment: @GrantThomas I have a difficult time with this.  The philosophy of this site seems to be "simple, direct questions, simple, direct answers", which I tend to adhere to.  Yet, when I answer the question simply, I see other people critique that I didn't answer other unasked questions.  In this case, data validation, which is a rather extensive topic, not really solved by just `TryParse`.  My opinion is if the questioner has a further question about data validation, they can ask it.  Yet I see the flipside that beginners may need an extra nudge.  I'm conflicted on how to answer in these cases.

Comment: Maybe I should ask about this on Meta...

Comment: Your answer is technically correct enough to get the desired result under the right circumstances, and validation surely is quite a topic to get into, but it need not overshadow the solution and there's almost a responsibility to at least outline how a given solution could fail - estimating the audience.

Answer (score 2):

Others are correct, you will need to transform the value, but just using `int.Parse` could cause an error, and `val = int.TryParse` isn't how you use `int.TryParse`, so, a correction:

```
int result = 0;
if (int.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out result)) {
  pt1D.X = result;
} else {
  // input isn't an integer
}
```

Another thing to mention would be that `Pen` implements `IDisposable`, so you should dispose of it when you're finished using the thing; you can do this by explicitly calling `Dispose` or with a `using`:

```
using (Pen graphPen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2)) {
  // do what you need with the pen, 
  // it will be disposed when exiting this scope
}
```

Comment: okay that worked thanks
what about working with four text boxes i mean drawing lines using four text boxes

Comment: For more textboxes just shake some more of the same at it.

Comment: @GrantThomas I'm not really sure why, but that phrasing you used (shake some more at it) got me to chuckle.

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint_1(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    int value = 0;
    Pen graphPen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);
    Point pt1D = new Point();
    Point pt2D = new Point();
    pt1D.X = (int.tryParse(textBox3.Text, out value)) ? value : 0;
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(graphPen, pt1D, pt2D);

}
```

Comment: `int.TryParse` returns a bool, so that wont work.  Also there is no `Int` in C#, only `int` or `Int32`.

Comment: so than what can i do

Comment: fixed it, it should now work.

Comment: hey i want to take four text boxes and draw and draw a line on an image. How can i do it.

Comment: Edited for robustness.